# What are the lines on the wheels of the Perseverance rover called? Are they different than Curiosity's?

Tags: mars, nasa, rovers, perseverance

CNET's [NASA narrows down Mars 2020 rover names: Hello, Fido?](https://www.cnet.com/news/nasa-narrows-down-mars-2020-rover-names-hello-fido/) includes the image below.

I'm not sure if the rover is moving and a rolling shutter was in use, or if the lines on the wheels are really wavy somehow, so I thought I'd ask:

**Question(s):**

1. What are the lines on the wheels of the Insight rover called?
2. Are they actually "wavy" as shown in the image?
3. Are they different than those on the Curiosity rover?

---

Click each image for full size or see the original image linked below

[image: Mars 2020 rover wheel] [image: Mars 2020 rover wheel]

[image: Mars 2020 rover wheel]  [image: Mars 2020 rover wheel]

Complete image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzxkk.jpg

original giant size: https://cnet3.cbsistatic.com/img/OMgFU-dyAN7_bqtQCGMMVADCY88=/2019/12/18/56a896f7-98ff-4a05-8b4d-97f99ee29891/pia23499-hires.jpg (imgur shrinks it)

Comment: Are we sure these are the final flight-model wheels? Curiosity's wheels (especially with the JPL Morse code) look significantly different.

Comment: @Dragongeek good point; that should be confirmed, thanks!

Comment: @Dragongeek they were apparently redesigned because MSL's wheels had poor endurance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Partial answer because I learned a new word.

The lines / treads on the wheels are called "[grousers](https://www.space.com/nasa-mars-2020-rover-no-curiosity-twin.html)" and they are indeed [wavy](https://www.planetary.org/explore/space-topics/space-missions/mars2020.html).

Why:

> Extensive testing in JPL's Mars Yard has shown these treads better<sup>1</sup>
>   withstand the pressure from sharp rocks but work just as well on sand.

(from the 1st link)

<sup>1</sup>In comparison to Mars Science Laboratory's wheel design

Comment: Compared to straight grousers or chevron grousers, the tradeoffs are complicated.  Here's the full analysis.  https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/2014/6/i-SAIRAS2014_Hiroaki_grouser.pdf

Comment: @uhoh I read through that paper...and it's pretty intense! Don't think I could do it justice. Also it only seems to address chevron vs straight grousers, not "wavy" ones.

Comment: I've edited the question to match current state of knowledge because "wavy grousers" deserves marquee status (new question title).

Comment: [Why is NASA sending wavy grousers to Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48435/12102)

Comment: @uhoh lol, great question title.